# Exit from bash in git terminal

Tags: git

I'm coming from Windows backgroud, and try to use some of tool in linux environment, like  git version control. So when I using this tool,  there are some misuse about the functionality.  For example, I dont know--what I must press--to exit from bash console, when I unintentionally pressed  `bash` command in that terminal.

Comment: Why is that a problem? That's what Bash looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `exit` or press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> (EOF). Those exit shells, for the most part, and you’ll be back in the parent shell.